# ObjectListView adding items to it

Tags: vb.net

I am a bit lost and I would like to add some items to a Fast ObjectListView. what I have is not working, and I cant seem to find anything online with vb.net samples

```
    Dim LvItm As BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem = lstMain.Items.Add("title")
    With LvItm
        .SubItems.Add("name")
        .SubItems.Add("last")
        .SubItems.Add("phone")
        .SubItems.Add("address")
        .EnsureVisible()
    End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectListView works completely different from normal ListView, usually you dont add individual items.
In short:
- create columns
- set aspect names of created columns to property names of your objects
- point objectlistview to list of objects
See example below:

```
Imports BrightIdeasSoftware

Public Class Person
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property last As String
    Public Property phone As String
    Public Property address As String
End Class

Dim LvItm As New Person With {.name = "John",
                              .last = "Smith",
                              .phone = "555-69997-44",
                              .address = "Main Str. 1"}
Dim LvLst As New List(Of Person)
LvLst.Add(LvItm)

ObjectListView1.View = View.Details
ObjectListView1.Columns.Add(New OLVColumn With {.Text = "Name",
                                                .AspectName = "name"})
ObjectListView1.Columns.Add(New OLVColumn With {.Text = "Last Name",
                                                .AspectName = "last"})
ObjectListView1.Columns.Add(New OLVColumn With {.Text = "Phone",
                                                .AspectName = "phone"})
ObjectListView1.Columns.Add(New OLVColumn With {.Text = "Address",
                                                .AspectName = "address"})
ObjectListView1.SetObjects(LvLst)
```

With everything set-up you can add items to the list or manipulate in any way, 
hitting `ObjectListView1.SetObjects(LvLst)` again to refresh view.

You can also add items to ObjectListView directly:

```
Dim p As New Person
p.name = "Steve"
p.last = "Wilson"
p.phone = "777-888-9987"
p.address = "First Str. 1"
ObjectListView1.AddObject(p)
```

Remember that items added directly were not added to your List(Of Person)

Comment: thanks your code works, I have a little issue and is that I already have the columns defined so by using this code I end up with 8 columns instead of the 4 originals.. how do I make it work ?

Comment: Remove all lines where columns are added in my code:         
'ObjectListView1.Columns.Add(New OLVColumn' etc.

Comment: one more thing, is it possible to have the "person" class removed and just have it all inside a button ?